# Read and jump first line and anothers lines in file

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

How I can read a .dat file with struct like that: ( A = ALPHANUMERIC && N = NUMERIC )

```
0AAAAAAAANNNN (233 BLANK SPACES ) 999999 ( SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE )
1NNNNNNNNNNNNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
1NNNNNNNNNNNNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
1NNNNNNNNNNNNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
1NNNNNNNNNNNNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA (194 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
9 (245 BLANK SPACES) 999999 (SEQUENTIAL NUMBER ONE BY ONE)
```

So, I know, how I can make a program to read this in C/C++ or in C#, but, I try to make in Cobol, just for study....

But, I don't know what the command I need to use to open the file with this style ( I just know the:

```
ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

I think, exist a another command to open with custon instructions... i don't know...
So, btw, how I can open the file and read the informations ??

( i just need to read the line 1 on time, and, I need to read the line 2 and 3 always paried ... 4 and 5 && 6 and 7 && 8 and 9 ... )
and, I whant to show that information with DISPLAY ( just for study )
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this below your FD:

```
01  INPUT-RECORD.
    05  IR-RECORD-TYPE PIC X.
        88  INPUT-RECORD-IS-HEADER VALUE '0'.
        88  INPUT-RECORD-IS-DATA1 VALUE '1'.
        88  INPUT-RECORD-IS-DATA2 VALUE '2'.
        88  INPUT-RECORD-IS-TRAILER VALUE '9'.
    05  FILLER PIC X(whatever).
```

You may need a "trailing" byte for a record-delimiter, I don't know, and you'll have to sort out the lengths, as they seem to vary.

These in Working-Storage:

```
01  INPUT-RECORD-HEADER.
    05  IRH-RECORD-TYPE PIC X.
    05  IRH-ITEM1 PIC X(8).
    05  IRH-ITEM2 PIC 9(4).
    05  FILLER PIC X(233).
    05  IRH-SEQUENCE PIC X(6)
01  INPUT-RECORD-DATA1.
    05  IRD1-RECORD-TYPE PIC X.
    05  IRD1-ITEM1 PIC 9(14).
    05  IRD1-ITEM1 PIC X(19).
    05  FILLER PIC X(194).
    05  IRD1-SEQUENCE PIC X(6)
01  INPUT-RECORD-DATA2.
    05  IRD2-RECORD-TYPE PIC X.
    05  IRD2-ITEM1 PIC X(33).
    05  FILLER PIC X(194).
    05  IRD2-SEQUENCE PIC X(6)
01  INPUT-RECORD-TRAILER.
    05  IRT-RECORD-TYPE PIC X.
    05  FILLER PIC X(245).
    05  IRT-SEQUENCE PIC X(6).
```

You have to read each record, one at a time. Identify it. Put it in the correct W-S definition. When you read a "2" you can process the "1" you have stored along with the "2".

My datanames aren't very good, as I don't know what your data is. Also I have not "formatted" the definitions, which will make them more readable when you do it.

Answer (score 1):

For OpenCOBOL, here is a sample standard in/standard out filter program:

```
   >>SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED
  *> ***************************************************************
  *><* ===========
  *><* filter
  *><* ===========
  *><* :Author:    Brian Tiffin
  *><* :Date:      20090207
  *><* :Purpose:   Standard IO filters
  *><* :Tectonics: cobc -x filter.cob
  *> ***************************************************************
   identification division.
   program-id. filter.

   environment division.
   configuration section.

   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select standard-input assign to keyboard.
       select standard-output assign to display.

   data division.
   file section.
   fd standard-input.
       01 stdin-record     pic x(32768).
   fd standard-output.
       01 stdout-record    pic x(32768).

   working-storage section.
   01  file-status         pic x  value space.
       88 end-of-file             value high-value
          when set to false is          low-value.

  *> ***************************************************************
   procedure division.
   main section.
   00-main.

   perform 01-open

   perform 01-read

   perform
        until end-of-file
            perform 01-transform
            perform 01-write
            perform 01-read
   end-perform
   .

   00-leave.
   perform 01-close
   .

   goback.
  *> end main

   support section.
   01-open.
   open input standard-input
   open output standard-output
   .

   01-read.
   read standard-input
        at end set end-of-file to true
   end-read
   .

  *> All changes here
   01-transform.
   move stdin-record to stdout-record
   .
  *>

   01-write.
   write stdout-record end-write
   .

   01-close.
       close standard-input
       close standard-output
   .

   end program filter.
  *><*
  *><* Last Update: dd-Mmm-yyyy
```

and here is a demonstration of using LINAGE that just happens to read in a text file.

```
  *****************************************************************
  * Example of LINAGE File Descriptor
  * Author: Brian Tiffin
  * Date:   10-July-2008
  * Tectonics: $ cocb -x linage-demo.cob
  *            $ ./linage-demo <filename ["linage-demo.cob"]>
  *            $ cat -n mini-report
  *****************************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. linage-demo.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
      select optional data-file assign to file-name
          organization is line sequential
          file status is data-file-status.
      select mini-report assign to "mini-report".

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD  data-file.
   01  data-record.
      88 endofdata        value high-values.
      02 data-line        pic x(80).
   FD  mini-report
      linage is 16 lines
          with footing at 15
          lines at top 2
          lines at bottom 2.
   01  report-line         pic x(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  command-arguments   pic x(1024).
   01  file-name           pic x(160).
   01  data-file-status    pic 99.
   01  lc                  pic 99.
   01  report-line-blank.
      02 filler           pic x(18) value all "*".
      02 filler           pic x(05) value spaces.
      02 filler           pic x(34)
          VALUE "THIS PAGE INTENTIONALLY LEFT BLANK".
      02 filler           pic x(05) value spaces.
      02 filler           pic x(18) value all "*".
   01  report-line-data.
      02 body-tag         pic 9(6).
      02 line-3           pic x(74).
   01  report-line-header.
      02 filler           pic x(6) VALUE "PAGE: ".
      02 page-no          pic 9999.
      02 filler           pic x(24).
      02 filler           pic x(5) VALUE " LC: ".
      02 header-tag       pic 9(6).
      02 filler           pic x(23).
      02 filler           pic x(6) VALUE "DATE: ".
      02 page-date        pic x(6).

   01  page-count          pic 9999.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   accept command-arguments from command-line end-accept.
   string
      command-arguments delimited by space
      into file-name
   end-string.
   if file-name equal spaces
      move "linage-demo.cob" to file-name
   end-if.

   open input data-file.
   read data-file
      at end
          display
               "File: " function trim(file-name) " open error"
          end-display
          go to early-exit
   end-read.

   open output mini-report.

   write report-line
      from report-line-blank
   end-write.

   move 1 to page-count.
   accept page-date from date end-accept.
   move page-count to page-no.
   write report-line
      from report-line-header
      after advancing page
   end-write.

   perform readwrite-loop until endofdata.

   display
      "Normal termination, file name: "
      function trim(file-name)
      " ending status: "
      data-file-status
   end-display.
   close mini-report.

  * Goto considered harmful?  Bah!  :)
   early-exit.
   close data-file.
   exit program.
   stop run.

  ****************************************************************
   readwrite-loop.
   move data-record to report-line-data
   move linage-counter to body-tag
   write report-line from report-line-data
      end-of-page
          add 1 to page-count end-add
          move page-count to page-no
          move linage-counter to header-tag
          write report-line from report-line-header
              after advancing page
          end-write
   end-write
   read data-file
      at end set endofdata to true
   end-read
   .

  *****************************************************************
  * Commentary
  * LINAGE is set at a 20 line logical page
  *  16 body lines
  *   2 top lines
  *   A footer line at 15 (inside the body count)
  *   2 bottom lines
  * Build with:
  * $ cobc -x -Wall -Wtruncate linage-demo.cob
  * Evaluate with:
  * $ ./linage-demo
  * This will read in linage-demo.cob and produce mini-report
  * $ cat -n mini-report
  *****************************************************************
   END PROGRAM linage-demo.
```

With those samples, along with Gilbert's answer, you should have enough to tackle your problem, with the caveat that these examples are shy on proper error handling, so be careful is this is homework or a paid assignment.  For an example of standard input/output or by filename depending on command line arguments (or lack thereof), see the ocdoc.cob program in the OpenCOBOL FAQ.

Offtopic: Output of an ocdoc pass over ocdoc.cob itself can be seen at http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/ocdoc.html  (Why mention it?  The COBOL lexicon highlighter for Pygments has just been accepted into main.  Any Pygments pulled after version 1.6 will allow for COBOL (context free) lexical highlighting.)

Answer (score 0):

You write an ordinary Cobol program that reads a file.

The first byte (character) of the record is either 0, 1, 2, or 9.

Define a Working-Storage area (01 level) for each of the 4 record types.  Then, after you read the record, you move it from the input area to the appropriate Working-Storage area for the record.

Then you process the record how you wish from one of the 4 Working-Storage areas.